# Javascript - Loading gif appears

Tags: javascript, html, image, loader

I have a page where a random image is loaded using a javascript function.

The below is in the head tag.

```
function pickimg(){ 
var imagenumber = 101 ;
var randomnumber = Math.random() ;
var rand1 = Math.round( (imagenumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1;
images = new Array
images[1] = "images/1.jpg"
images[2] = "images/2.gif"
images[3] = "images/3.jpg"
images[4] = "images/4.jpg"
images[5] = "images/5.gif"
images[6] = "images/6.jpg"
images[7] = "images/7.jpg"
images[8] = "images/8.jpg"
images[9] = "images/9.jpg"
var image = images[rand1]
document.randimg.src = image
}
</script>
```

And then this in the body:

```
<body onLoad="pickimg()">
<a href="" onClick="pickimg();return false;"><IMG SRC="images/ajax-loader.gif"     name="randimg" border=0></a>
```

A random image is selected. When you click the image, a new one is loaded and THEN displayed. This can take a second or two. I want a ajax-loader to appear as the next image is loading, after the user has clicked. I'm new to this and I've tried various things but nothing gives me the results I desire. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, please replace that code with the following (before end script tag), so that it is proper:

```
function pickimg(){ 
   var imagenumber = 101, ext,
        images = new Array(10), i=0,
        randomnumber = Math.random(),
        rand1 = 1 + Math.round((imagenumber-1) * randomnumber);
    while (++i<10) {
        ext = (i===2||i===5)? ".gif" : ".jpg";
        images[i] = "images/"+ i + ext;
    }
    document.randimg.src = images[rand1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm a bit confused, I should replace all the javascript in my head tag with the code you've provided? Btw, I'm using 101 images, various jpg gif and png files. I only put 9 in my OP for obvious reasons.

Comment: OH. Well, hopefully you can read the script I wrote. But, if it's random extensions for the images, maybe my edit won't help... with that many images.

Comment: That script is very poorly written. Don't forget semi-colons. And, objects are instantiated with programmatic parenthetical notation. ref: new Array (WTF?).

Answer (score 0):

Preload the loading image. Then instead of changing the source directly to the new image, change it to the loader, then change it to the new image. This will cause the loader to display immediately (since it's preloaded), and then the new image will appear when it is ready.

Answer (score 0):

An answer, though the Ajax loader is nowhere to be found in your example code, is the following:

```
getImage: function(fn){
                var url = "/apps/blah/imgpath/",
                    $imgContentContainer = $("myselector");
                $imgContentContainer.html(loadingImgTag);
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: url + fn,
                    success: function(d){ $imgContentContainer.html(theAjaxLoadedImg); }
                });
            }
```

Comment: I should note that loadingImgTag is referencing the response aforementioned by Kolink. Preload an image, then always display it immediately before the ajax call to load the new image.

Comment: It's interesting that your "obvious answer" includes the use of jQuery even though the OP neither uses it in their question or mentions it. Obviously, I must have missed the memo.

Comment: Its also quite interesting that no code herein makes use of an "ajax loader". And, since 95% of web application make use of jQuery these days, I made an assumption... hopefully, its not inappropriate.

Comment: I've made a colloquial, and far more diplomatic, edit to my original answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies guys. But I'm still very confused. I'm extremely novice when it comes to javascript. I still don't quite understand your suggestion Joe.

At the moment. When you click on of the random images, it loads the next random picture and then displays it. I want a .gif to appear over the loaded image untill the next one is loaded/displayed.